# Create a persistent class in eclipse for abap (ADT)

Tags: eclipse, abap, abap-adt

Can I create a persistent class from within Eclipse? How?

In the ABAP Classbuilder I can simply tick a checkbox to do that, but in eclipse, I did not see something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, at the moment this is not possible, and as far as I know, it has not been decided whether it will be implemented at all.

You neither can make changes on them through eclipse, that will show you the following warning:

> Persistent classes are currently not supported by this editor